# Angular 2 which one is the right way to create user authentication

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm new to angular 2 and I have to implement user login authentication for angular2 project but while surfing on internet people were posted lot of methods for creating angular 2 authentication. some of them are like

1. using firebase
2. using JWT authentication..etc

So which one is the right way. is there any official authentication available for angular2?

Comment: Are you using firebase as DB ?

Comment: No, planned to use web service @RonakBhatt